# Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How I can resolve this?

> Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Folder structure is fine. But still error.

Have I done something wrong in creating spring boot application? how to create a spring boot mvc project?

```
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class SpringsocialApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringsocialApplication.class, args);
        }
    }



    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String index()
        {
            return "index";
        }

    }

    #view resolver
    spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
    spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

directory structure

[image]

Comment: First of all, EnableWebMvc on a Spring Boot application is a really bad idea: it disables all the default setup of MVC done by Spring Boot. Second, where is your index view?

Comment: Thank you James.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment. Yes I found that @EnableWebMvc is no longer needed when we annotated our class with @SpringBootApplication . 
And I found the link which explains this problem more http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration. Thank you.